# Maximum value of a linear function over an euclidean norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to solve:

$\underset{S}{max}$ $y^TQ^{-1}S$

$subject$ $to$ $||S||_2 \leq p$

Where $y$ is a given vector, $Q$ is an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and $S$ is the optimization variable. The KKT conditions written below are a bit inconsistent for me:

$||S||_2 \leq p$ (constraint),

$\lambda \geq 0$ (dual variable),

$\lambda(||S||_s-p)=0$ (compl. slackness),

$y^TQ^{-1}+ \frac{\lambda S^T}{2||S||_2} = 0$ (first order condition of Lagrangian).

I can't go further. What is the real solution for this simple convex model?

Comment: If $\lambda>0$, you can use compl. slackness.

Comment: Indeed, it is greater than 0. All we know is then ||S||=p

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz... no need for KKT.

Comment: Can you please clarify how I can use that?

Comment: $\|S\|_2 \le 0$? The only way that is possible is if $S = 0$.

Comment: $a^T b \le \|a\| \|b\|$ with equality only if $a=\mu b$ for some $\mu \ge 0$.

Comment: Your final argument is wrong. How can you divide by a vector...What the first order condition of the Lagrangian says is that $S$ has to be a multiple of $Q^{-1}y$ (although you appear to have a sign error), and completing the arguments will lead to the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maximize the inner product, you should have $S$ parallel to $Q^{-T}y$. Hence $S= tQ^{-T}y$ for some positive scalar $t$. To maximize the expression, you pick $t$ such that the constraint is active, and you will obtain $S  = p \frac{Q^{-T}y}{||Q^{-T}y||}$